# Combining dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge 2 data frames in python using the code given below. Here is the information about data frames

- **nlxdf** with columns name 'NlxTTL' and 'NlxTime'
- **pittldf** with columns 'pittlState','pittlSTC','piVideoSTC'

Here is how the **pittldf** data looks like:

```
pittlSTC    pittlState
1.39e+10    0
1.4e+10     1
1.4e+10     0
1.4e+10     1
1.4e+10     0
1.4e+10     1
1.4e+10     1
1.4e+10     1
1.4e+10     1
1.4e+10     0
1.4e+10     1
1.4e+10     0
1.4e+10     1
```

and here is how the **nlxdf** looks like

```
NlxTTL  NlxTime
0   13788602129.0
1   13789602296.0
0   13790602496.0
1   13791602629.0
0   13792602829.0
1   13793602996.0
0   13794603162.0
1   13795603329.0
0   13796603496.0
1   13797603662.0
0   13798603829.0
1   13799603996.0
0   13800604162.0
1   13801604329.0
```

Here is the script used by me:

```
import scipy.io as sio
import pandas as pd

data = sio.loadmat('testRun2.mat')

nlxTTL = list(data['NlxTTL'][0])
nlxTime = list(data['NlxTime'][0])
pittlState = list(data['pittlState'][0])
pittlSTC = list(data['pittlSTC'][0])
piVideoSTC = list(data['piVideoSTC'][0])

nlxdf = pd.DataFrame({'NlxTTL':nlxTTL, 'NlxTime':nlxTime})
pittldf = pd.DataFrame({'pittlState': pittlState, 'pittlSTC':pittlSTC, 'piVideoSTC':piVideoSTC})

merged_df = pittldf.merge(nlxdf, left_on='pittlState', right_on='NlxTTL', how='outer')
```

After running the script, I was expecting the following outcome:

```
NlxTTL  NlxTime    pittlSTC    pittlState
0   13788602129.0   1.39e+10    0
1   13789602296.0   1.4e+10     1
0   13790602496.0   1.4e+10     0
1   13791602629.0   1.4e+10     1
0   13792602829.0   1.4e+10     0
1   13793602996.0   1.4e+10     1
0   13794603162.0     NA        NA
1   13795603329.0   1.4e+10     1
0   13796603496.0     NA        NA
1   13797603662.0   1.4e+10     1
0   13798603829.0     NA        NA
1   13799603996.0   1.4e+10     1
0   13800604162.0   1.4e+10     0
1   13801604329.0   1.4e+10     1
NA      NA          1.4e+10     0
NA      NA          1.4e+10     1
```

But I am not able to get this output. How should I proceed? Thanks!

**EDIT** I am trying to merge 2 dataframes on keys which are not unique (binary values).

I will explain, how this data was obtained. This data is collected after sending TTL pulse to 2 different machine as LOW(0) HIGH(1) LOW(0) HIGH(1) and so on. and recording time respectively. So for each machine, you should receive either HIGH(i.e. 1) or LOW(i.e. 0). But on one of the machine, I ended up missing some inputs as shown in **pittldf** with consecutive 1's or HIGH where it should have repetition of LOW(0) and HIGH(1).

I was wondering if there is a way I can combine these dataframes to align the times properly using the State(either 1 or 0).

Comment: Sorry but I don't get the merge here, you're trying to merge on binary values which are not unique, how are you expecting this to match here?

Comment: I understand your question, but is there any way I can proceed using this. I will updated my question to involve the information provided by you. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between the 2 datasets, please edit your question to explain this further, is it 1 to 1, 1 to N, N to N....

Comment: It is 1 to 1 relation that is for each value of NlxTTL, there should be a value of pittlSTC which is missing in my dataset as explained in the Edit above